# How to make full URLs via Xpath from relative ones?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

There are a site, e.g.

```
  http://example.com
```

with such a page:

```
 <div id="topnews">
      <a href="/news/topnews1.html"> Top news1 </a>
      <a href="/news/topnews2.html"> Top news2 </a>
      <a href="http://sport.example.com/news/topnews3.html"> Top news complex </a>
 </div>
```

Is it possible via pure Xpath to get these 3 URLs:

```
 http://example.com/news/topnews1.html
 http://example.com/news/topnews2.html
 http://sport.example.com/news/topnews3.html
```

?

To extract relative URLs we could use:

```
   //div/a/@href
```

But

```
  concat('http://example.com',  //div/a/@href)
```

returns only 1 row (first one), not 3 different values.

And I do not know to elegant detect and process last full URL.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible in XPath 1.0, are you open to a XPath 2.0 solution?

Comment: Yes, I think I could try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

Not possible in XPath alone.

### XPath 2.0

This XPath 2.0 expression,

```
for $h in //a/@href return
    if (starts-with($h, 'http:/'))
    then $h
    else concat('http://example.com',$h)
```

returns

```
http://example.com/news/topnews1.html
http://example.com/news/topnews2.html
http://sport.example.com/news/topnews3.html
```

for your document, as requested.

Comment: Is it possible with XPath 1.0 make only first two links?

Comment: In XPath 1.0 you could `concat()` a fixed number of `href` attributes and use some separator other than newline.